# how set set RGB components separately in opengl

Tags: opengl

Suppose I have previously rendered some set of pixels on the screen that each contain one of the following RGB values:

```
0.0 0.0 0.0    in other words, black
1.0 0.0 0.0    in other words, red
0.0 0.0 1.0    in other words, blue
1.0 0.0 1.0    in other words, purple
```

Now I want to be able to selectively toggle the red or blue components of what's on the screen to 1.0 or 0.0, without affecting the other color components of what's on the screen.

For instance, say some pixel contains 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, purple, and I want to turn off the red in that pixel without changing the value of blue.

Assumption here is at this point I don't know if the blue in that pixel is 0.0 or 1.0. I just want to turn the red part of it off.

Also, I don't want to have to segregate the red changes from the blue changes into separate sets of vertex attributes, i.e. I'd like to be able to set just the red component of one set of pixels and set the blue component of another set of pixels in one call to glDrawArrays(). Also, within each set of pixels some of the reds I want to be able to set to 1.0 while others I want to set to 0.0 and likewise for the blue.

I have a hunch this would involve some creative usage of glBlendFunc(), but dang if I can figure out how to do it.

Note that what I am trying to accomplish here is a poor man's 3D rendering on a typical PC screen using a homemade set of goggles with a red lens for the right eye and a blue lens for the left eye. Think how they did 3D for black and white movies back in the 1950s.

Anybody got some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Your last paragraph suggests to me that what you really want is "How can I render anaglyph stereoscopic output". Just selectively rendering to the red and blue channels as the rest of your question describes won't actually accomplish that, unfortunately. The wavelengths of the red and blue primaries in the screen are not a perfect match for the usual anaglyph lenses, so you'll actually need to mix in some of the other channels to get a convincing look. You also need to contend with the fact that both left and right image need their own depth buffer.

Comment: Have you looked at glColorMask?

Comment: DMGregory: The eventual target platform is Oculus. This red/blue lens thing is just a proof of concept that I can cheaply implement and test on a laptop, so  the look doesn't need to be that convincing. Also, the algorithm that generates the vertices to be rendered doesn't use depth buffers.

Comment: Maximus: Thanks for the suggestion on glColorMask(). I'm assuming this setting would apply to every fragment rendered in a given all to glDrawArrays(), so to use it I'd need to segregate the red color fragments from the blue color fragments and render them in separate calls to glDrawArrays(), right? Ideally I'd be able to do what glColorMask() does on a per fragment basis, i.e. somehow encoded in the vertex attributes so that the color mask would be applied in the fragment shader.

Comment: @user256552 - render the scene twice, once with glColorMask (0,1,1,1) and the second time with glColorMask (1,1,0,1), using either a slightly different camera angle or a tweaked projection matrix to achieve the separation.